# How to add msgpack support in swagger rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, msgpack

I am using `swagger-docs` in my rails app for API's documentation. It worked fine. Now I add `msgpack` in API response to speed up, that also works fine.

But the issue I am facing now is that `swagger-docs` not unpack that response I send, due to which it not showing a response.

Here is my API response

```
render json: {:success=>true, :all_models=>all_models,:page=>page}.to_msgpack, :status=>200
```

How can I add unpack response or add msgpack in swagger?

Comment: Can you show swagger code?

Comment: yes sure.........